# flutter chat app with stream.io members page

Tags: flutter, getstream-io, querying

i am using stream io for my flutter chat app and i have a couple of 'group' channels, meaning there's multiple users in the channel. i am having problems integrating a members page. does anybody knows how to use 'querying members' from https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/query_members/?language=dart#query-options ? any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/helpers.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/screens/screens.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/themes/theme.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:stream_chat_flutter_core/stream_chat_flutter_core.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/stream/app.dart';

class CommunityProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static Route routeWithChannel(Channel channel) => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => StreamChannel(
            channel: channel,
            child: const CommunityProfileScreen(),
          ));

  const CommunityProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CommunityProfileScreen> createState() => _CommunityProfileScreenState();
}

class _CommunityProfileScreenState extends State<CommunityProfileScreen> {
  final channelListController = ChannelListController();

  final List<String> _areaOfInterest = [
    'PersonalDevelopment',
    'AcquiringNewSkills',
    'Mentoring',
    'Coaching',
    'WealthManagement',
    'InvestingOnPassiveIncome',
    'BusinessDevelopment',
    'BuildingANetwork',
    'GrowingMyBusiness',
    'PartnershipAndAlliances',
    'RecruitmentOfTalents',
    'Lifestyle',
    'LuxuryExperiences',
    'TheArtOfLiving'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChannelListCore(
      channelListController: channelListController,
      filter: Filter.and([
        Filter.and(
          [
            Filter.equal('type', 'messaging'),
            Filter.in_('members', [
              StreamChatCore.of(context).currentUser!.id,
            ]),
            Filter.notIn('members', const ['influential-brands']),
          ],
        ),
        Filter.nor([
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[0]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[1]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[2]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[3]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[4]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[5]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[6]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[7]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[8]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[9]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[10]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[11]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[12]),
          Filter.equal('id', _areaOfInterest[13]),
        ]),
      ]),
      sort: const [SortOption('name', direction: SortOption.DESC)],
      emptyBuilder: (context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leadingWidth: 54,
            leading: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: IconBackground(
                  icon: CupertinoIcons.chevron_back,
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
            ),
            title: const _AppBarTitle(),
          ),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('No Other Members', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
        );
      },
      errorBuilder: (context, error) => const DisplayErrorMessage(),
      loadingBuilder: (
        context,
      ) =>
          const Center(
              child: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: AppColors.accent,
        ),
      )),
      listBuilder: (context, channels) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leadingWidth: 54,
            leading: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: IconBackground(
                  icon: CupertinoIcons.chevron_back,
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
            ),
            title: const _AppBarTitle(),
          ),
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) {
                    return _ProfileTile(
                      channel: channels[index],
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: channels.length,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _ProfileTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ProfileTile({Key? key, required this.channel}) : super(key: key);

  final Channel channel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(ChatScreen.routeWithChannel(channel));
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.2))),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Avatar.medium(
                    url: // needs help
                    ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                        // needs help,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            letterSpacing: 0.2,
                            wordSpacing: 1.5,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _AppBarTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _AppBarTitle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Members Of Community',
                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black)),
            const SizedBox(height: 2),
          ],
        )),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 16,
        ),
        Hero(
          tag: 'community-profile-picture',
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
            child: Avatar.medium(
                url: Helpers.randomPictureUrl(),
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ not yet unfortunately

Comment: have you completely made hat with getstream. io

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ what is hat?

Comment: typo MISTAKE
chat*